# how to have nested loop inside foreach to calculate car rental rate and days

Tags: php

I'm working on a car rental website. I managed to display relevant information for each car using foreach associative array. Now the problem is in displaying the rental days and amount in a table for each car...

For instance:

```
 car 1
 image for car 1
 days 1    7     30
 amt  100  300    1500

 car 2
 image for car 2
 days 1    7     30
 amt  250  400    3500
```

and so on.... How can I achieve this with this code?

```
<?php
//select query

$query_showall = "SELECT rental.*,car_name.*,gallery.*,car_make.* FROM rental,car_name,gallery,car_make  WHERE car_name.carName_id=gallery.carName_id AND car_name.carMake_id=car_make.carMake_id  
     AND rental.carName_id=car_name.carName_id GROUP BY rental.carName_id";

//while loop
$result_showall = mysql_query($query_showall) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row_showall = mysql_fetch_array($result_showall)) {
    $carMake_all = $row_showall['carName'];
    $carmake_1[$row_showall['carName_id']][] = $row_showall;
    $car_id[] = $row_showall['carName_id'];
}

// foreach to display all info

foreach ($carmake_1 as $make_1 => $name_1) {

    foreach ($name_1 as $n_1) {
        if (isset($n_1['detail'])) {
            $detail_1 = $n_1['detail'];
            $detail_1 = nl2br($detail_1);
        } else {
            $detail_1 = "Car Detail";
        }
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td class='carname'><h2><?php echo $n_1{'carName'}; ?></h2></td>
            <td rowspan="2" valign="top" class="cardetail"><?php echo $detail_1; ?>
                <br/><br/>

                <a class="book" href="book_now.php?name_id=<?php echo $n_1['carName_id']; ?>">Book <?php echo $n_1['carName_id']; ?></a>
    </td></tr>



echo"<tr><td class='img'>{$n_1['carName_id']}<img src='management/uploads/{$n_1['carMake_id']}/{$n_1['gallery']}' width='400' height='200'>";?>
    </td></tr>

<tr>

    <td>
        .....here to display days and amounts for each car....
    </td>
</tr>
```

DATABASE STRUCTURE for Rental table

rental_id  rental_days rental_amount carName_id

1                                1                                                  50                                                            101
2                                   7                                                  550                                                          101
3                                   30                                               5050                                                  101

I tried to display day and amount for each car like this by retaining the above query.
    echo "{$n_1['rental_days']}";
    echo "{$n_1['rental_amount']}";

It displays only the first data keyed in for that car id in rental table. Obviously didn't
 loop.Can anyone suggest how can I loop in the above code?

Comment: Since you don't explain anything about your db structure or how you're retrieving/storing that pricing information, we can't really help you. But since you already have a query and are displaying some of the data from it, I can't see why you're unable to add the extra fields/data yourself... unless you've just copy-pastaed this code and are suffering from cargo-cult programming syndrome.

Comment: @Marc B I din't copy paste.. I can actually call out the date and amount like $n_1['rental_days'];    $n_1['rental_amount']; but it doesn't loop through the rental table as one carName_id has multiple days and amounts.

Comment: Be aware of the SQL injection vulnerability you currently have. Somebody could try to book car `'; DROP TABLE car_name; --`

Answer (score 0):

You have a sorted array of data that contains semi-duplicates like:

```
id  make  model  days_rented  amount paid
1   ford  escort 10           500
1   ford  escort 24           1100
2   honda accord 5            350
```

So you keep track of the last id.  If the current id is different to the last one, you display the html for a new car.  If you get the same car again, you just display the rental details.

```
$last_car_id = -1;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_showall)) {
  $car_id = $row['carname_id'];
  if ($last_car_id != $car_id) {
    // we have a new car
    if (!$last_car_id === -1) { // if this is not the very first car
      // close the rental details table, and the car's html container
    }

    // build html for new car, display all details that are specific to this car like make and model
    // build html to open a table containing rental details

    $last_car_id = $car_id;

  }
  // html to display rental details as a table row
}
// close the rental details table, and the car's html container (same code as above)
```

Comment: thanks for helping...I tried but didn't turn out to be what I expect. It didn't show all days and amounts for each car instead just displayed one.